# IE 7 Accented charcters in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, character-encoding

I am facing an issue displaying accented characters in IE7.The same charcters render fine in FF,Chrome

Platform: Java

Issue:
Accented characters in the JSP get rendered fine.
Accented characters in the JS do not get rendered fine on IE7 alone, instead we see weird characters

Solutions Tried:
Used charset="UTF-8" in places where we are importing the JS files

For eg. the accented e in the javscript appears as a box, closely represented by [].

Comment: Can you give examples of the problematic characters?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure you're using the correct encoding (UTF-8) in your source files (both js and jsp) and use

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in your HTML template.

As far as the source files, you can easily check how they are encoded within your IDE (*File properties* in Eclipse, *format tab* in Notepad++, etc).